# Getting amount of children with XOM

Tags: java, xml, xom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locations>
    <location id="83">
        <location_name>name</location_name>
        <company_name>company a</company_name>
        <machines>
            <machine id="12">A</machine>
            <machine id="312">B</machine>
        </machines>
    </location>
    <location id="85">
        <location_name>name</location_name>
        <company_name>company c</company_name>
        <machines>
            <machine id="21">A</machine>
            <machine id="45">B</machine>
        </machines>
    </location>
</locations>
```

I'm using XOM and trying to get all location names but I don't know how.

```
Element root = doc.getRootElement();    
int i = 1;
Element child = (Element) root.getChild(i);
while(child != null)
{
    System.out.println(child.getFirstChildElement("location_name").getValue());
    child = (Element) root.getChild(i++);
}
```

But this don't work, it shows only the first name, on second loop it shows error.

And secound question: what `getChildCount()` counts??

Comment: Give us a clue, what is the error?

Comment: Please show us the stack trace, without this very hard to diagnose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getChild(int i)` returns the i-th child *node*, not necessarily the i-th child element. Use `getChildElements("location")` and iterate over the list returned. Another approach is to use an XPath query on the root element.

Also, the javadoc is quite informational: http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/.